# Incorrect use of useEffect() when filtering an array

Tags: reactjs

I have this React app that's is getting data from a file showing in cards. I have an input to filter the cards to show. The problem I have is that after I filter once, then it doesn't go back to all the cards. I guess that I'm using useEffect wrong. How can I fix this?

```
import { data } from './data';

const SearchBox = ({ onSearchChange }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type='search'
        placeholder='search'
        onChange={(e) => {
          onSearchChange(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState(data);
  const [searchField, setSearchField] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const filteredCards = cards.filter((card) => {
      return card.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase());
    });
    setCards(filteredCards);
  }, [searchField]);

  return (
    <div>
      <SearchBox onSearchChange={setSearchField} />
      <CardList cards={cards} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cards original state will be forever lost unless you filter over original data like `const filteredCards = data.filter()`.

though, in a real project it's not interesting to modify your cards state based on your filter. instead you can remove useEffect and create a filter function wrapped at `useCallback`:

```
  const filteredCards = useCallback(() => cards.filter(card => {
    return card.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase());
  }), [JSON.stringify(cards), searchField])

    return (
    <div>
      <SearchBox onSearchChange={setSearchField} />
      <CardList cards={filteredCards()} />
    </div>
  );
```

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-react-basic-filter?file=src/App.js)

**about array as dependency (cards)**

adding an object, or array as dependency at useEffect may crash your app (it will throw `Maximum update depth exceeded`). it will rerun useEffect forever since its object reference will change everytime. one approach to avoid that is to pass your dependency stringified `[JSON.stringify(cards)]`

Comment: Thanks! Yes, my mistake was using setCards to change the original state. I have a questions, what is the difference of your solution to just using `
  const filteredCards = cards.filter((card) => {
    return card.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase());
  });` ?
I read that "useCallback will return a memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of the dependencies has changed", but what does it mean? Using useCallback is better if the cards arrays is really big, right?

Answer (score 3):

you should Include both of your state "Card", "searchedField" as dependincies to useEffect method.once any change happens of anyone of them, your component will re-render to keep your data up to date,

`useEffect(() => { // your code }, [searchField, cards]);`